# How to reload component with React Router when using dynamic URLs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have an app that pulls posts and their tags from Firebase Firestore and uses React Router for navigation. When I click a tag to view posts with that tag (e.g. root.com/tags/food) food posts display. If I then click another tag (e.g. root.com/tags/travel) because we're already on the 'tags' page, router doesn't refetch the page. How do I correctly do this? (I'm not currently using Redux and a suggested solution, 'ComponentWillRecieveProps' is depreciated now). I'm using functional components.

Setup

I have a TagList component that gets a list of (clickable) tags from Firestore, a Feed component that shows a list of posts, and a TagFeed component which shows a list of posts when a particular tag is clicked on in the TagList component, with React Router alternating between them using 'match' to get the tag.

TagList e.g.

```
{ docs && docs.map(doc => (
     <ul key={doc.id}>
         <li>
             <button>
                  <Link to={`/tag/${doc.myTag}`}>
                      {doc.myTag}
                  </Link>
             </button>
         </li>
     </ul>
 ))}
```

TagFeed.js

```
const TagFeed = ({match}) => {

    const theTag = match.params.tag;
    ....

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTags = projectFirestore.collection(collection)
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .where("myTag", "==", `${theTag}`)
            ....
```

Router setup in App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Nav/>
        <PostForm/>
        <Tags/>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Feed}/>
            <Route path="/tag/:tag" exact component={TagFeed}/>
            <Route path="/" render={() => <div>404</div>}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

So, every time a Tag is clicked the TagFeed component is called, and the param from the URL is passed into the Firebase query, but the TagFeed component isn't called again if we're already viewing it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `tag` param needs to be a dependency for the `useEffect` that gets the new stuff from FB and updates the state. That way it will run whenever the tag changes

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @Jayce444, that works.  When compiling it does output "React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'theTag'" - can I just ignore this?

Comment: Your syntax for the tag variable declaration and `useEffect` is probably not *quite* right, since that warning shouldn't be there. But technically yes, if it's working you can just ignore it.

Comment: @Jayce444 Ha, yes, probably. Thanks again, much appreciated.